# Как решить задачи в E-olymp c помощью php?

Tags: php

Есть такой замечательный сайт: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/21
Решил я порешать задачи, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не правильные ответы, но на машине всё правильно работает. Подозреваю что дело в записи в файл. Как работать с такими компиляторами ?

Код моей задачи:

```
<?php
    function readFiles($dir) {
        return file($dir, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    }

    $dir = __DIR__ . '/input.txt';
    $outputFile = __DIR__ . '/output.txt';
    $firstLine = explode(' ', readFiles($dir)[0]);
    $countExpires = $firstLine[0];
    $percent = $firstLine[1];
    $expiresArr = explode(' ', readFiles($dir)[1]);
    while(count($expiresArr) !== 1) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < round(count($expiresArr) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); $i++) {
            var_dump($expiresArr);
            echo '<br/>';
            $expiresArr[] = ($expiresArr[$i] + $expiresArr[$i + 1]) * (1 - ($percent / 100));
            $expiresArr = array_diff_key($expiresArr, [$i, $i + 1]);
            array_values($expiresArr);
            sort($expiresArr, SORT_NUMERIC);
            var_dump($expiresArr);
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($outputFile, number_format($expiresArr[0],2, '.', '') . "\n");
?>
```

Comment: Так там же написано: _«На данный момент система поддерживает 3 языка и 6 разных копиляторов: Borland Delphi 7.0, Free Pascal, Gnu C++, Java Developement Kit, Microsoft Visual С++ 6.0, Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0.»_ Где тут PHP?

Comment: Они недавно систему сменили, там уже php есть, а все эти ссылки не рабочие

Comment: Ну и до кучи, Ваш код неверно работает, если значения во второй строке повторяются, например, `1000 1000 1000 1000`.

Comment: Благодарю, я доработал и обновил код выше, всё равно не хочет работать

Comment: `100 100 100 500 500` - выдается странный результат.

Comment: Да, я тоже заметил, но суть не в этом. Там 20 тестов и хотя бы один должно правильно показать, но нет, всё неправильно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85247/discussion-between-netahaki-and-yaant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала ознакомиться со [справкой](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/blogs/posts/8). Обычно там пишут как с чем работать с примерами кода.

> На данный момент система поддерживает 3 языка и 6 разных копиляторов: Borland Delphi 7.0, Free Pascal, Gnu C++, Java Developement Kit, Microsoft Visual С++ 6.0, Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0.

Comment: Я лазил по всему сайту, но там нет примеров работы с php

Comment: @Netahaki Потому что решения на php на данный момент писать нельзя, и автор ответа, и справка на сайте вам об этом говорит.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Судя по [этому](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions?q=%2Bcompiler%3A%22Judge%20PHP%22), все же можно. Хотя сайт, конечно, удивляет своей кривизной в плане информативности.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы поставили галочку `Решение использует файлы для чтения и записи`, то ответ надо писать в файл. А не выводить через `echo` как это сделано у вас.

Comment: Это я знаю, я использовал разные методы. Галочку ставил если работа с файлами, а если нет, то убирал, всё равно не работает

Comment: @Netahaki а какой-то текст с ошибкой и причиной провала оно не пишет в ответе?

Comment: пишет что не "Неправильный ответ"

Comment: @Netahaki я попробовал отправить ответ и он до сих пор проверяется. уже 4 дня. так себе сервис